# Migrating old xcode projects into latest version

Tags: xcode4.5

I have problem with memory management and leaks(Potential leak of an object) of old xcode projects.Can i Migrate these projects to new xcode4.5 with Automatic reference counting to overcome the above issues. If this possible means how can i made it? and Is this right way or what else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can definitely do that & that too with using Xcode latest version itself. 
XCode is intelligent enough to change the non-ARC into ARC and also can use the latest Syntax.

Open your project into Latest version of Xcode, probably 5.0.1 & then go to menu 
Edit-> Refactor-> Convert to Objective-C ARC

There are many other options under Refactor menu. You can try those.

[image: Here is the screen shot]